# Update apk when previous certificate will expire before 2033

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I've to upgrade an android app on the market.

I try to sign with app with my previous certificate (`Certificate expires on Thu Oct 08 10:22:43 CEST 2020.`) and the market return the following error:

`"Market requires that the certificate used to sign the apk be valid until at least October 22, 2033. Create a new certificate."`

If I try whit a new certificate the market says

`"The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version"`

What's the solution for that?

What will append in 2020 if Google will change the limit to 2043? Nobody can update this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't, unless you change the package name.

Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies) (under **Signing Strategies**).

Comment: How about signing with both the older cert that expires in 2020 and the new cert that expires in the crazy distant future? Would that work?